# Understanding the following CDF expression

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

I am trying to understand how the following CDF expression is obtained.

$h_1 = \text{min}(f, g)$ ---(1)

where $f, g$ are independent and identically distributed random variables.

$F_{h_1}(h) = \text{Pr}(h_1 < h) = \text{Pr}(\text{min}(f, g) < h)$ ----(2)

$F_{h_1}(h) = 1-(1-\text{Pr}(f<h))(1-\text{Pr}(g<h))$ ----(3)

$F_{h_1}(h) = $F_{f}(h)+ F_{g}(h) - F_{f}(h)*F_{g}(h)$----(4)

where $F(.)$ denotes CDF.

I had understood eq. (1) and (2) clearly, but not getting how eq. (3) and (4) is obtained.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: if $h$ is the minimum, how does it compare to $f$ and $g$?

Comment: Thank u so much sir for ur response....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align}
F_{h_1}(h) 
&= Pr(min(f,g) < h) \\
&= 1 - Pr(min(f,g) \geq h). 
\end{align}
If the minimum of $f$ and $g$ is bigger than $h$, then this means that both are bigger than $h$.
So, we get
\begin{align}
F_{h_1}(h) 
&= 1 - Pr(min(f,g) \geq h) \\
&= 1 - Pr(f \geq h \text{ and } g \geq h).
\end{align}
Since, $f$ and $g$ are independent we know that
\begin{align}
F_{h_1}(h) &= 1 - Pr(f \geq h \text{ and } g \geq h) \\
&= 1 -Pr(f \geq h) \cdot Pr(g \geq h)\\
&=1 -\big(1 - Pr(f < h) \big) \cdot \big(1 - Pr(g < h) \big)\\
&= 1 - \Big( \big(1-F_{f}(h)) \cdot (1-F_{g}(h) \big) \Big)\\
&= 1 - \big( 1 + F_{f}(h)F_{g}(h) - F_{f}(h) - F_{g}(h) \big)\\
&= F_{f}(h) + F_{g}(h) - F_{f}(h)F_{g}(h).
\end{align}
We have now established equation 3 and 4.

Comment: Dear Niels...Thank u so much for your detailed answer ...Your explanation helped me to understand the concept thoroughly...